# When I would use a specific similarity coefficient over another?

Tags: similarity, cosine-distance, jaccard-coefficient

Like using Jaccards over Dice.
I want real examples, of when I would prefer to use Jaccards, Dice, Cosine or any other similarity coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

- **Jaccard** - measures similarity of assymetric, binary attributes. For example, [if you have insurance claims](http://www.dataminingapps.com/2016/06/can-you-explain-how-the-jaccard-index-can-be-used-for-distance-calculation/) with binary attributes ("poor driving record", "premium paid in cash") you can compare claims with those attributes.
- **Cosine** - measures similarity between vectors, like feature vectors. Could be used in a recommender system where a user asks to see items similar to some selected item.
- **Dice** - equivalent to F1-score. Often used in image segmentation, comparing a model's output with reference masks.